# Controlling Comma Input for a Data Grid View When Validating Numerical Data Input

Tags: vb.net, validation, input

I have a data grid view where I have to restrict the entry to numerical inputs (integers and decimal places) for one of the columns. The users are inputting values directly to the data grid view. In total, there are 2 columns, one of which is read-only. I have the following code right now:

```
Private Sub dgv1_CellEndEdit(By Val sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Form.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv1.CellEndEdit

    If (e.ColumnIndex =1) Then 'This is the column where I want to restrict input
       If dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value <> Nothing Then
            Dim value As String = dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString()
            If Not Information.IsNumeric(value) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry.")
                dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = String.Empty
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
     End If

End Sub
```

The issue I'm coming across is that if I enter something like 3,3 or 4,2  (where the , is in between or after the numbers) it does not consider that as invalid entry and there's no error. However any other special character, + or - or @, in the same format is recognized and shows the error message. Why is this code not recognizing that as invalid and how can I include that check? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Europe, commas are used to separate units from tenths like English uses dots (10.3 = ten and three-tenths = 10,3 in Europe), thus VB recognises it as a valid number. I would change your conditional to the following:

```
If (Not Information.IsNumeric(value)) OrElse value.Contains(",") Then
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - I did not know that. This works great!